# SQL query to retrieve Fname and Last Name and populate Last name in Fname field in result if Last name is not present for an employee

Tags: sql

Looking for SQL query to retrieve Fname and Last Name with a condition to populate Last name in Fname field in result if Last name is not present for an employee.

Comment: Sample data?  What have you tried?  What database are you using?

Comment: Please show your table structure, also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. If I understood your question correctly?

Did you mean "Populate the `LastName` with the `FirstName` if the `LastName` is `null` or `Empty`" ?

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN [LastName] is null or [LastName] = '' THEN [FirstName] ELSE [LastName] END as 'Last Name'
,[FirstName] as 'First Name'
FROM tbl_emp
```